# Restrict results to only dates that are in the next month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

What I am trying to code is "give it to me if the review date is in the next month."

```
Select id, review_date
from Table
Where (review date is in any part of the next month next month)?
```

I tried:

```
where CAST("Revw_Dt" AS date) = ADD_MONTHS(Current_Date, 1)
```

but that only returns the review date in the next month = to todays date.
I need it if it is any where in the following month.

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys! for the quick response!! You all are the bomb.com! I found I need an added layer now.... "give it to me if the review date is in the next month." AND it is the 10th or after the current month.... Yall solved part A, can you give some love on part B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use combination of the `add_months` and `trunc` functions.

```
Select * from your_table
Where trunc(Revw_Dt, 'month') = trunc(add_months(current_date,1),'month');
```

Cheers!!

Comment: you think you could help with part B of the where? AND it is the >= 10th of the current month

Comment: `Your_date >= trunc(current_date, 'month') + 10`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach, that will happily use an existing index on the date column:

```
SELECT id, review_date 
FROM mytable 
WHERE 
    review_date >= ADD_MONTH(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month'), 1)
    AND review_date < ADD_MONTH(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month'), 2)
```

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS` is an Oracle function, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: ah yes you are right, I was fooled by the `CAST()` expression. I just updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the month components of the review date with next month's date:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Revw_Dt) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, 1));
```